# Is present perfect a good choice

Tags: present-perfect

> This is really the best compilation I have heard for years . The nnnnn is really a great band. I have never heard from them before

Is present perfect a good choice or would past perfect be better ?

I ve chosen present perfect because it is a very recent compilation. I think past perfect would be OK if I had written before the comp was released

Answer (score 2):

The present perfect is the *only* choice here.

You would only use the past perfect to speak of your opinions in the past.

> When I first heard xxxxx, I thought it was the best compilation I *had heard* for years.
>
> When I heard the nnnnn last  weekend I thought they were great. I *had never heard* them before.